# Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in actionButton

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, networkonmainthread

I know that this exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. I am running my code in `AsyncTask`.

I'm trying to connect to database in an a button's `setOnClickListener`
How should I proceed, and avoid this Exception? I mean, how to set my code in order to execute database connection in a `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Check out tutorial on google. e.g. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: ,` how to set my code in order to execute database connection in AsyncTask`. You dont need to. The AsyncTask is for network connections.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

ADD code below in onCreate. under setContentView

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Hope. It will help you!!!